Output from evaluating python source code blocks in org-mode not correct
After switching to Mac from Windows, the output of my python org-mode code blocks are not working properly. It keeps printing what seems to be the backend python call instead of the code output. And not even the full command, seems to cut the command short (as in the example below the Result stops before the input to the python "print" command).
The code itself is executing as expected and the results are printed in the interactive python session buffer (in the example case the *py* buffer. Still with the annoying backend call at the top though). However, it is not being appended in the org-mode buffer itself. Any tips on how to fix the following would be highly appreciated:

Output the actual python outputs in the org-mode buffer
not output the "__PYTHON_EL_eva(...)" part

Here is an example illustrating the issue:
#+BEGIN_SRC python :python python3 :session py :results output  :noweb yes :tangle no

print("Somehow the output of these source blocks are not displayed correctly? I did not have this issue with emacs on Windows...")

#+END_SRC

#+RESULTS:
: __PYTHON_EL_eval("try:\n    with open('/var/folders/ty/x6hl83sn5cz667zpq3yk02lr0000gn/T/babel-PJfJby/python-HFmx85') as __org_babel_python_tmpfile:\n        exec(compile(__org_babel_python_tmpfile.read(), __org_babel_python_tmpfile.name, 'exec'))\nexcept:\n    raise\nfinally:\n    print('

This is how it looks in the interactive python buffer:
__PYTHON_EL_eval_file("/var/folders/ty/x6hl83sn5cz667zpq3yk02lr0000gn/T/py66QmoC", "/var/folders/ty/x6hl83sn5cz667zpq3yk02lr0000gn/T/py66QmoC", True)
Somehow the output of these source blocks are not displayed correctly? I did not have this issue with emacs on Windows...
org_babel_python_eoe
>>> 

Running Emacs 29.4 on macOS Sonoma 14.4
I have tried to set :results value which returns None as expected. I notice this does not print the backend string. I have of course also tried reading the documentation on org-mode and the source code blocks, but was not able to figure it out from that alone.

Thank you @NickD, that solved the issue. ✅

If you haven't done so already, you might want to upvote  the answer by @Ian in the linked question (and maybe also the question that led to that answer), but you'll need to wait until you get a little reputation (15 points apparently).

Yeah I tried, but I don't have the reputation to do so yet...

That's OK: you can get back to it when you do have enough reputation. In the meantime, here are ways that you can gain (or lose) reputation. In particular, see the last paragraph on that page.
